# Template Stack Class: No Data Appears in Stack

Tags: c++, templates, stack

<strike>The pop() function is the one with the return type error. The function is says it returns a Stack object but the data is in a Node struct. How do I make it return the proper data?</strike>

<strike>According to my display function it looks like no data gets in the stack.</strike>

Adding newNode->mData = data and checking via debugging it looks like things are getting in the stack. It appears the display function may be the problem.

I'm also unsure if my push and isExist funcitons are right...

## Edited: pop push and isExist

```
/*      Pre:  The stack is initialized and searchKey is available
 *     Post:  The function retuns true if the searchKey exists in the queue;
 *            otherwise return false
 *  Purpose:  To determine if a given value exists in the stack or not
 *************************************************************************/
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isExist(T searchKey)
{
    bool exist = false;
    Node<T> *temp = mHead;

    if (mHead == NULL)
    {
        exist = false;
    }

        else if (temp->mData == searchKey)
        {
         exist = true;
        }

    else
    {
        while (temp->mNext != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->mData == searchKey)
            {
                exist = true;
                break;
            }

            temp = temp->mNext;
        }
    }

    return exist;
}


/*      Pre:  The stack is initialized
 *     Post:  The first node in the stack is removed, and its content is
 *            returned.  If the stack is empty return the default value
 *            for the given data type
 *  Purpose:  To remove the first node in the stack
 *************************************************************************/
template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    //Temp holds the mem location of the data
    //that will be popped/returned
    Node<T> *temp = mHead;

    if (mHead == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
        cout << "The stack is empty!";
    }

    //Makes the next node in the stack the top one
    else if (mHead->mNext == NULL )
    {
        mHead = NULL;
        mTail = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        mHead = mHead->mNext;
    }

    //Increment the counter down for the popped node
    mCount--;

    return temp->mData;
}


/*      Pre:  The stack is initialized
 *     Post:  The new node is added at the beginning of the stack.
 *            Duplication is allowed
 *  Purpose:  To add a new node at the beginning of the stack
 *************************************************************************/
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T data)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
    newNode->mData = data;

    //If the stack is empty
    if (mHead == NULL && mTail == NULL)
    {
        mHead = newNode;
        mTail = newNode;
    }

    //Otherwise mHead will be the new node's next node
    //The new node becomes the head
    else
    {
        newNode->mNext = mHead;
        mHead = newNode;
    }

    //Increment the counter to reflect the new node
    mCount++;
}
```

## Display Function

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::display()
{
   Node<T> *tmp;

   if (isEmpty())
      cout << "Empty Stack\n";
   else
  {
      tmp = mHead;

      while (tmp != NULL)
      {
          cout << tmp->mData << " ";
          tmp = tmp->mNext;
       }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```

## Rest of Stack Class

```
    #ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack {
   private:
       template <class T>
       struct Node
       {
          T       mData;
          Node<T> *mNext;

          /*      Pre:  None
           *     Post:  This object is initialized using default values
           *  Purpose:  To intialize date object
           *************************************************************************/
          Node()
          {
             mData = T();
             mNext = NULL;
          }


          /*      Pre:  None
           *     Post:  This object is initialized using specified data
           *  Purpose:  To intialize date object
           *************************************************************************/
          Node(T data)
          {
             mData = data;
             mNext = NULL;
          }
       };

      Node<T> *mHead, *mTail;
      int     mCount;

   public:
      Stack();
      ~Stack();

      int  getCount();

      void clear();
      void display();
      bool isEmpty();
      bool isExist(T searchKey);
      T    pop();
      void push(T data);
};


template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
   mHead  = NULL;
   mTail  = NULL;
   mCount = 0;
}


template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
   while (!isEmpty())
      pop();
}


template <class T>
int Stack<T>::getCount()
{
   return mCount;
}


template <class T>
void Stack<T>::clear()
{
   while (!isEmpty())
      pop();
}


template <class T>
void Stack<T>::display()
{
   Node<T> *tmp;

   if (isEmpty())
      cout << "Empty Stack\n";
   else
   {
      tmp = mHead;

      while (tmp != NULL)
      {
         cout << tmp->mData << " ";
         tmp = tmp->mNext;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}


template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
   return mCount == 0;
}



#endif
```

Comment: Could you give us the exact error your compiler is giving you?

Comment: I fixed the error by returning a Stack<T> object and using -> to get at the member data. The new problem is according to my display function it looks like no data gets in the stack.

Comment: @Angel You can't ask an entirely different question once the previous question has been resolved. You need to make a new post for that.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Seeing as how nobody actually answered the original question, I saw fit to edit the post to ask the new question.

Comment: @0x499602d2 you're right, sorry. AndyG thanks!

Comment: Rule of Three!! No copy constructor or assignment operators in your class, so 'returning' a Stack<T> from a function can only end badly.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You're missing a step in your push to set the data!</strike>

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T data)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
    //HERE! vv
    newNode->mData = data;
    //THERE! ^^

    //If the stack is empty
    if (mCount == 0)
    {
        mHead = newNode;
        mTail = newNode;
    }

    //Otherwise mHead will be the new node's next node
    //The new node becomes the head
    else
    {
        newNode->mNext = mHead;
        mHead = newNode;
    }

    //Increment the counter to reflect the new node
    mCount++;
}
```

(User fixed strikethrough text in an edit)

Other things to think about: What is this `mTail` variable, and what should be happening to it?

Look at your `isExist` function... Ask yourself what happens if you push a number and then ask if that number exists? Will it work as intended? What happens if you try to pop from an empty stack? What happens if you call isExist on an empty stack?

Comment: I'm still getting the same output of all 0's when I added that line of code.

Comment: @Angel: Can you add the code to show your display function? Also show us your Stack constructor function.

Comment: Sure. When I debug in VS Express Desktop it looks like all the data it making it in the list.

Comment: I've posted my entire stack template class!

Comment: @Angel: There is a great deal wrong with your code. Specifically, what is `mTail` even used for? What happens if you try to pop from an empty stack? What happens if you call isExist on an empty stack? What happens when you push one element and then call isExist to search for it? I don't feel comfortable fixing all the code for you, considering the comment you included that certified to your instructor that the Stack class was all your own work.

Comment: I believe I fixed pop from an empty stack, isExist on an empty stack, isExist on a one element stack. You've been doing a great help of telling me where to look for the mistakes! We're allowed to get help from the professor, tutors and place online like this :)